# Printer backup batch script not working

Tags: windows-server-2008

I'm trying to write a little batch script which is supposed to backup all printers on a Win2008 print server using printbrm.
Here's what I've got so far:

```
%comspec% /c spool\tools\printbrm -B -S \\SERVERNAME -F Print_Backup.printerExport -O FORCE
```

All this does is open a command shell, just to close it instantly, though I have no idea why.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to workaround the problem by simply adding a 'del' clause at the beginning of the script. It seems like the option '-o force' wasn't really doing what it was supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the full path `%WINDIR%\System32\Spool\Tools`, there's no guarantee that %comspec% will start in the right directory.
The `/c` will make the script close as soon as it's done so add a `pause` as the last line of the batch file to see what messages show up.